# asp.net mvc route setting for infinite parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, routes

If I want my url like:

```
http://domain/product/detail/category1/category2/.../categoryN
```

How to set the RouteConfig for this, the category level was not fixed.

Comment: Do you want the API to accept a list of categories?

Comment: Yes, it's ok, but if it had other solutions(not accept list of categories), I also want to know that, thx

Comment: You would need to use a 'catch-all' route definition - refer [this article](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/f41d04f7-14f6-4d28-a2ce-fbbeb985fffc.aspx) for an example